# Python Script that is changes by execution

Tags: python, list

how can I write a script that it changes by execution?
For example, two a have script exist from two row:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sliced_list = list[0:1]
```

Executing it, 2nd row should be:

```
sliced_list = list[1:2]
```

and then,

```
sliced_list = list[2:3]
```

I want to modify variable "sliced_list" everytime I run this file.

Comment: `List = [0:1]` (etc) is not even valid syntax.

Comment: I updated it. so how can I do it. what i need to research?

Comment: `List[0:1]` is now syntactically valid but it is pointless - it will evaluate a slice and then immediately discard it.

Comment: I suggest you try this https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/ to learn lists if you start from the beginning it will lead up to running scripts

Comment: @alaniwi ok just think as printing. I just want you to understand what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is not something you should ever want to do, since it is likely to result in non-deterministic behavior, and in the event of a bug its possible to completely overwrite your script and lose data.

If you want to change the date your script is operating on you should store it persistently in some fashion. This could be in a separate file somewhere or in an environment variable.

But to do what your asking you would need to open the script, copy the contents, and modify the content as you desire like this:

```py
with open("/path/to/script.py", 'r+') as script:
    contents = script.read()

    # ... some string logic here

    # Point cursor to the beginning of the file
    # If the original contents were longing than the new contents
    # you'll have unwanted data at the end of the file.
    script.seek(0)
    script.write(contents)
```

Comment: `contents` will be empty here - in `a+` mode the file pointer will be positioned at the end.

Comment: @alaniwi You're absolutely right about that. You'd need to open the file to read contents before closing to write the updated contents.

Comment: @joshmeranda Not necessarily closing - could open in `r+` mode, read contents, then `script.seek(0)` and write the updated contents. But the whole thing is a bad idea anyway, as you say.

Comment: @alaniwi Yep, I was just testing that before I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the start index into a file when you run the script. Then increment it and save it. Something like what is shown below.

```
import os
List=[1,2,3,4,5]
file=open('file.txt','r+')
start_index=int(file.read())
print(List[start_index:start_index+1])
file.close()
os.remove('file.txt')
file=open('file.txt','w')
file.write(str(start_index+1))
file.close()
```